# Why are print_r and return returning different values?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

I have the following custom function in PHP / Wordpress.

```
function GetAncestors($post_id, $ancestors = array()) {

    $query = 'SELECT `wp_terms`.term_id, `wp_terms`.name, `wp_term_taxonomy`.parent FROM `wp_terms` LEFT JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` ON `wp_terms`.term_id = `wp_term_taxonomy`.term_id WHERE `wp_terms`.term_id = '.$post_id;
    $term_data = RunQuery($query)[0];
    array_push($ancestors,$term_data);
    if($term_data[parent]!='11') GetAncestors($term_data[parent],$ancestors);

    else print_r($ancestors);
    //else return $ancestors;

}
```

If I `print_r` the array, it returns the expected result. If I `return` the value of the array and `print_r` it outside of the function (which is what I want to do), it returns a blank string.

**Results from `print_r`:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [term_id] => 95 [name] => PDR (Appraisals) [parent] => 91 ) [1] => Array ( [term_id] => 91 [name] => Your career, learning and development [parent] => 14 ) [2] => Array ( [term_id] => 14 [name] => You At ... [parent] => 11 ) )
```

Why is this?

Comment: Post this data(print_r and after return print_r)

Comment: show the output also

Comment: @sergio, N.M.N, output added.

Comment: Just a note, in function names, it should always start with a lowercase letter, not an uppercase one as you did. That naming convention apply to class names where the firt letter should be uppercase

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks - I'm self taught, so I've missed conventions like that,

Comment: I'm also self taught :-), takes a while to learn the basics. I'm still making mistakes, hahaha. You should read the following on [coding standards in Wordpress](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/)and [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) which is used by Wordpress. Just another note on syntax, always use curlies (`{}`). The syntax you are using is hard to read and a nightmare to debug later. Curlies are supported by all code editors, your is not. :-). Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
// Changed ancestors to reference
// Changed constant 'parent' to string
function GetAncestors($post_id, &$ancestors = array()) {

    $query = 'SELECT `wp_terms`.term_id, `wp_terms`.name, `wp_term_taxonomy`.parent FROM `wp_terms` LEFT JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` ON `wp_terms`.term_id = `wp_term_taxonomy`.term_id WHERE `wp_terms`.term_id = '.$post_id;
    $term_data = RunQuery($query)[0];
    array_push($ancestors,$term_data);
    if($term_data['parent']!='11') {
        GetAncestors($term_data['parent'],$ancestors);
    }
}

$ancestors = array();
GetAncestors($id, $ancestors);

print_r($ancestors);
```

Personally I'd write it like this for utility:

```
function GetAncestors($post_id, &$ancestors = null) {
    if (null === $ancestors) {
        $ancestors = array();
    }

    $query  = 'SELECT `wp_terms`.term_id, `wp_terms`.name, `wp_term_taxonomy`.parent FROM `wp_terms` LEFT JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` ON `wp_terms`.term_id = `wp_term_taxonomy`.term_id WHERE `wp_terms`.term_id = '.$post_id;
    $result = RunQuery($query);

    if (count($result) > 0) {
        $count = 1;
        $term_data = $result[0];
        array_push($ancestors,$term_data);

        if($term_data['parent']!='11') {
            $count += GetAncestors($term_data['parent'],$ancestors);
        }

        return $count;
    }

    return 0;
}

if (GetAncestors($id, $ancestors) > 0) {
    print_r($ancestors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the return flag:

```
print_r($ancestors, true);
```

From php doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

> If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return
>   parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return
>   the information rather than print it.